# Active Form Ajax Validate Yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I need the following validation rules on a form via AJAX:

- The validation of courses only occur if the Dropwn List code is 2, 3, 4.
- In this case the Company Name and Address Company fields are required.
  I tried this code for validation model condition nomeempresa. This code for Model validate in case `tipoincricao_codigo == 2`:

  ```
  public function rules() {
      return [
          [
              ['nomeempresa'/*,'cnpj','emailempresa','telefonefixoempresa','telefonecelularempresa', 'enderecoempresa', 'bairroempresa', 'cidadeempresa', 'estadoempresa', 'cepempresa'*/],
              'required',
              'when' => function ($model) {
                  return $model->tipoinscricao_codigo == 2;
              }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) { return $('#tipoinscricao_codigo').val() == 2;}"
          ]
      ];
  }
  ```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code... this is not a place where you come and get code written for you.

Comment: this code for Model validate in case tipoincricao_codigo ==2 [['nomeempresa'/*,'cnpj','emailempresa','telefonefixoempresa','telefonecelularempresa', 'enderecoempresa', 'bairroempresa', 'cidadeempresa', 'estadoempresa', 'cepempresa'*/], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
                return $model->tipoinscricao_codigo == 2;
            }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                return $('#tipoinscricao_codigo').val() == 2;
            }"],

Comment: tipoinscricao_codigo is at least "safe" right?

Comment: tipoinscricao_codigo it's required right.

Comment: Can you show the entire rules function?

Comment: Also are you sure that you are choosing value 2? and not 3 or 4 when you test this?

Comment: I tested for the values 3:04 too, but when the code is tipoinscricao 1 the CompanyName field is not required because in this situation the field is hidden. It happens that when I'm going to change from 1 to 2, 3 or 4 field is not again required understand?

Comment: I understand, but the code looks ok, there must be something else that you are not seeing outside the code you already show.

Comment: The code it works alone, but when the tipoinscricao for the CompanyName field is hidden, so that I did this code: 
 $('#cadastro-tipoinscricao_codigo').change(function(){
    if($('#cadastro-tipoinscricao_codigo').val()==1){
     $('#cadastro-nomeempresa').hide();
       $('label[for="cadastro-nomeempresa"]').hide();}

Comment: The code to hide and display the field company that makes it not work validation, would like to know some method to hide a field and validate this field dynamically on the screen to the user. It is it possible ?, maybe some method for Ajax ... Anyway ..